# How can I make a polished granite texture in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

Basically I'm trying to make a realistic polished granite texture to apply to my 3D model of a countertop... The granite resembles glass, as it's glossy... The countertop looks like this:

[image: 3D model of countertop]

The granite inspiration looks like this:

[image: Granite Inspiration]

Comment: What have you tried as far and what are you struggling with?

Comment: Does it need to be 3D relief or just a procedural material?

Comment: Easiest way is to follow a tutorial! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPaZYBFE8dY for instance.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a first shot, trying to keep it as simple as possible, in 2D:

[image]

It uses one softly quantized *Musgrave* texture for the main features, slightly stretched, for the grain direction, and another mixed to 'Darken' it, introducing sporadic, more isolated speckles. That branch also enriches the background a little..

[image]

On the left, your reference. On the right, the procedural texture. I'm sure you could tweak it a little further.

This does not go as far as attempting to simulate the crystalline transparent features. I personally think,  to do that, you'd have to go down the road of parallax mapping or somesuch.. a lot more node.,, but I could be wrong, there..

[image]

Comment: In my estimation, any attempt to do transmission and other components in the same shader leads to the problem of rays that enter the mesh and don't necessarily exit at a point that 'accepts' transmission, if that makes sense.  Perhaps it's a problem in general, but nowadays my theory is that a geonode system to distribute a manifold mesh for those elements would be better.  Haven't tested it.

Comment: Hi, @AllenSimpson! Sounds like a reasonable estimation to me. I've seen parallax with partial scattered transmission.. but glinting and internal reflection? Seems like fakery on fakery, and a miserable time figuring out how to make one fake compensate for another fake. But that might be pessimistic.. it's Rich Sedman territory ..:D